# Is it possible to modify a function's code?

Tags: python

With the following function:

```
def func(var):
    print (var)

x = func
```

Is it possible to modify the code of a function given `x`? Pretending the "compiled code" is a string. I mean something like this:

```
>>> x = func
>>> x_as_string = "print (var)"
>>> x_as_string_modified = x_as_string += "\n print('end of function')"
>>> x(2)
2
end of function
```

Comment: Not in anyway that would be useful. There's probably some way to patch a function's byte code directly, but that would be specific to CPython.

Comment: It should be possible, will be quite involved. I suggest taking a look at the `inspect` module.

Comment: I suspect this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/150985). _Why_ do you want to do this?

Comment: @martineau this is definitely an XY problem unless this user is curious about the intricacies of the language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't stress this enough: Don't ever use this on anything even mildly serious. Exec is dangerous and not a good idea.

But curiosity got the better of me so here's one way to literally add lines to code that is to be executed:

```
>>> import inspect

    def func(var):
        print (var)

    def terriblie_idea(arg, func = func, new_func_lines = []):
        func_string, call_string =  inspect.getsource(func), f"func({arg})"
        func_string += ('\n' + '\n'.join(new_func_lines)) if new_func_lines else ''

        exec(func_string + ';\n' +call_string)

>>> terriblie_idea(124, new_func_lines=["print(f'This code is dynamic! Your input was {arg}')", "print('end of function')"])
```

output:

```
>>> This code is dynamic! Your input was 124
    end of function
    124
```

This is similar to your idea in the fact that you can input new lines into your original function by passing them into the `terrible_idea` function as arguments. The function gets rebuilt and then called on the first argument of `terrible_idea`, which I should mention is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 1):

The method you express is a *very*, **very** bad idea.  Self-modifying code stains your karma, moves you farther from satori and nirvana, and lacks Buddha-nature.

What you *can* do decently is to write a function that parameterises your variations in a controlled way.  Then write a wrapper function to return custom varieties of the function per your choices.

```
def make_x(str):

    def inner(var):
        print(var)
        if str:
            print(str)

    return inner

orig = make_x(None)
new  = make_x("end of function")

orig(2)
new(77)
```

Output:

```
2
77
end of function
```

is that enough power for your needs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `inspect.getsource` and `eval`.

```
import inspect
import os.path

os_path_join_code = inspect.getsource(os.path.join)
```

and for eval:

```
sum = eval("1 + 2")
```

Now you put everything together and keep on exploring it. But this is definitely not the best approach for modifying code, you can always modify code behaviour by augmenting it, and it is very possible to do through pre-stablished code patterns. I would start by understanding python function decorator.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you look into what are called python `decorators`.

Consider the following code:

```
import functools

def decorator(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapped_f(*args, **kwargs):
        print('start of function')
        r = f(*args, **kwargs)
        print('end of function')
        return r
    return wrapped_f

@decorator
def print_strawberries():
    print("strawberries")

print_strawberries()
```

Even if you don't quite understand the code, know that the text printed to the console is:

```
start of function
strawberries
end of function
```

In some way, we have changed `print_strawberries`. The new version also prints `start of function` and `end of function`.

The notation `@decorator` is equivalent to the following:

```
def print_strawberries():
    print("strawberries")
print_strawberries = decorator(print_strawberries)
```

Even better that function decorators are classes which define their own `__call__` methods. `__call__` is the paren-paren operator `()`. That is `print("hello world")` is actually `print.__call__("hello world")`

```
class Decorator:
    def __init__(self, callable):
        self._callable = callable
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('start of function')
        r = self._callable(*args, **kwargs)
        print('end of function')
        return r

###################################################

@Decorator
def print_strawberries():
    print("strawberries")

print_strawberries()

###################################################

def add_two(x, y):
    return x + y
add_two = Decorator(add_two)

result = add_two(0, 1)
print(result)
###################################################
```