# How to run code on both python2 and python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

As a sort of exercise, I would like to try running a program on both python2 and python3. Here is the program:

```
def enter_name():
    name = raw_input('Please enter your name: ')
    print("Your name is: %s" % name)
```

Of course the above is written in `python2` as in `python3` `raw_input` is changed to `input`. I would like to write a wrapper that allows this `python2` code to run in `python3`. It would modify the source code to change the "raw_input" to "input". And would run like this:

```
@run_python3
def enter_name():
    name = raw_input('Please enter your name: ')
    print("Your name is: %s" % name)
```

And the decorator would convert the source code for the function raw_input to input if in a `python3*` environment. This is related to my previous question: [Is it possible to modify a function's code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58595847/is-it-possible-to-modify-a-functions-code). How could the above be done using a decorator (not something like `2to3`)?

Comment: This already exists: [six](https://six.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: or use try/except NameError to define `raw_input = input` if doesn't exist